# Prevent Blinking Cursor (IBeam) from a Read-Only RichTextBox

Tags: winforms, richtextbox

Is there anyway to prevent the cursor (IBeam) of a read-only `RichRextBox` from blinking whenever the textbox got focus?

I've tried to block the `WM_SETFOCUS` message from the `WndProc` but it causes the form to hang.

```
if( m.Msg == 0x0007 ) return;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to use Win32 APIs. Here's what you could do in VB:

```
'API declares
Private Declare Function HideCaret Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer
Private Declare Function ShowCaret Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer
'hide the caret in myTextBox
Call HideCaret(myTextBox.Handle)
'show the caret back..
Call ShowCaret(myTextBox.Handle)
```

and in C#

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "ShowCaret")]
 public static extern long ShowCaret(IntPtr hwnd);
 [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "HideCaret")]
 public static extern long HideCaret(IntPtr hwnd);
```

then make a call to

```
   HideCaret(richtextbox.Handle)
```

when ever you want to hide it.

Comment: As an addendum, I found success when calling it inside the event `textbox.GotFocus`

Answer (score 6):

Just to say that the Anirudh Goel answer does not work (at least in C#). The carat still there blinking :/

I found a solution at: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_21896403.html

His class always hide the caret, here is an improved one so you can choose to hide or not the caret.

**If you want to hide do not forget to set MustHideCaret to true**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Lm
{
    public class RichTextBoxEx : RichTextBox
    {
        private readonly object mustHideCaretLocker = new object();

        private bool mustHideCaret;

        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool MustHideCaret
        {
            get
            {
                lock (this.mustHideCaretLocker)
                    return this.mustHideCaret;
            }
            set
            {
                TabStop = false;
                if (value)
                    SetHideCaret();
                else
                    SetShowCaret();
            }
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int HideCaret(IntPtr hwnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "ShowCaret")]
        public static extern long ShowCaret(IntPtr hwnd);

        public RichTextBoxEx()
        {
        }

        private void SetHideCaret()
        {
            MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(ReadOnlyRichTextBox_Mouse);
            MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(ReadOnlyRichTextBox_Mouse);
            Resize += new EventHandler(ReadOnlyRichTextBox_Resize);
            HideCaret(Handle);
            lock (this.mustHideCaretLocker)
                this.mustHideCaret = true;
        }

        private void SetShowCaret()
        {
            try
            {
                MouseDown -= new MouseEventHandler(ReadOnlyRichTextBox_Mouse);
                MouseUp -= new MouseEventHandler(ReadOnlyRichTextBox_Mouse);
                Resize -= new EventHandler(ReadOnlyRichTextBox_Resize);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            ShowCaret(Handle);
            lock (this.mustHideCaretLocker)
                this.mustHideCaret = false;
        }

        protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MustHideCaret)
                HideCaret(Handle);
        }

        protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MustHideCaret)
                HideCaret(Handle);
        }

        private void ReadOnlyRichTextBox_Mouse(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            HideCaret(Handle);
        }

        private void ReadOnlyRichTextBox_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            HideCaret(Handle);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Easier method: attach this event to the Enter event of the RichTextBox:

```
  private void Control_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ActiveControl = null;
  }
```

Comment: This killed all the control in my form. Instead, I used ActiveControl = <MyFormClass>.ActiveForm; This prevents complete lockup.

Comment: @TheC4Fox I'm using it, attach the event ONLY to the RichTextbox ENTER event. This prevent the control from being focused at all by mouse click or keyboard TAB. With bit more effort you can make it target the next control when the user uses the TAB key. I modified the answer a bit to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

For me solution from Pedro77 didn't work too...
I've modified that class to:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Lm
{
    public class RichTextBoxEx : RichTextBox
    {
        private readonly object mustHideCaretLocker = new object();

        private bool mustHideCaret;

        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool MustHideCaret
        {
            get
            {
                lock (this.mustHideCaretLocker)
                    return this.mustHideCaret;
            }
            set
            {
                TabStop = false;
                if (value)
                    SetHideCaret();
                else
                    SetShowCaret();
            }
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int HideCaret(IntPtr hwnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "ShowCaret")]
        public static extern long ShowCaret(IntPtr hwnd);

        public RichTextBoxEx()
        {
        }

        private void SetHideCaret()
        {
            MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(ReadOnlyRichTextBox_Mouse);
            MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(ReadOnlyRichTextBox_Mouse);
            Resize += new EventHandler(ReadOnlyRichTextBox_Resize);
            HideCaret(Handle);
            lock (this.mustHideCaretLocker)
                this.mustHideCaret = true;
        }

        private void SetShowCaret()
        {
            try
            {
                MouseDown -= new MouseEventHandler(ReadOnlyRichTextBox_Mouse);
                MouseUp -= new MouseEventHandler(ReadOnlyRichTextBox_Mouse);
                Resize -= new EventHandler(ReadOnlyRichTextBox_Resize);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            ShowCaret(Handle);
            lock (this.mustHideCaretLocker)
                this.mustHideCaret = false;
        }

        protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MustHideCaret)
            {
                HideCaret(Handle);
                this.Parent.Focus();//here we select parent control in my case it is panel
            }
        }

        protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MustHideCaret)
                HideCaret(Handle);
        }

        private void ReadOnlyRichTextBox_Mouse(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            HideCaret(Handle);
        }

        private void ReadOnlyRichTextBox_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            HideCaret(Handle);
        }
    }
}
```

then put my RichTextBoxEx into (inside) Panel control...
that fixed getting blinking caret on mouse click...

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I have found the simple solution.

In your form's "Load" subroutine, add the line:

```
AddFocusHandlers(Me)
```

Then add to the bottom of your form's code the following. Stipulate the controls on which you wish this "blocking of entry" to occur in the "HideCaret" routine
(I have listed three textboxes belonging to my form):

```
Private Sub AddFocusHandlers(ByVal parentCtr As Control)
    Dim ctr As Control
    For Each ctr In parentCtr.Controls
        AddHandler ctr.LostFocus, AddressOf meLostFocus
        AddFocusHandlers(ctr)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub meLostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    LastFocused = DirectCast(sender, Control)
End Sub

'This routine will activate each time any of the listed controls are entered.
Private Sub HideCaret(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
               Handles tbDate.Enter, tbAttachments.Enter, tbTemplate.Enter
    LastFocused.Select()
End Sub
```

and finally place at the top of your form code (between the Class name and the first sub or function the following:

```
    Private LastFocused As Control  'Control which previously had focus
```

Then when the user clicks on any control shown in the list of controls in the "HideCaret" routine, the cursor simply stays in the previously selected control.
Isn't VB.Net wonderful? You can achieve almost anything you thought not possible.