# c# How can I make a textbox editable and non editable, on click? How about a transparent label?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I would like a textbox to appear rather disabled, and display a number.

[image]

So i've given it a dark background, i'd like it to have no cursor. I'd like it to not be editable. But i'd also like it to be clickable.

But when it is clicked,  i'd like it to have a white background colour, and be editable.

I know how to change the colour.

My problem is that when I set a textbox's editable property to false, then the method for when it is clicked, doesn't get triggered.

A workaround would be to have a transparent label over the top of it. Then that could get clicked(when that is clicked I could disable and enable the textbox).  But I don't know how to make a transparent label either.  And I tried a label with visible set to false, but that can't be clicked either.

[image]

Comment: Is this win forms?  WPI?  Another?

Comment: All you have to do is change the ReadOnly property to true assuming this is winforms

Comment: @JonathanCarroll that doesn't remove the cursor

Comment: You should tag your question accordingly

Comment: @roryap I created my project with this option http://i.imgur.com/fXsEsbj.png does that mean I should tag it winforms?

Comment: Yes that's winforms. As for the cursor, you can use this workaround : http://stackoverflow.com/a/734083/3922214 . All you have to do is put that function in the GotFocus event for the textbox.

Comment: @barlop are you familiar with setting `property` visible based on a bool value for example `someLabel.Visible = !someBoolValue;` this will toggle on and off on.. also set the property of the TextBox.ReadOnly true / false I think is better..

Comment: @MethodMan Yes but as mentioned in the q. Visible to false then makes an object not clickable. e.g. try putting a label in a form and setting visible to false, then click doesn't work on it

Comment: @JonathanCarroll thanks, i'll try that.. I understand winforms is old and I should be using WPF.. maybe i'll recreate/rewrite the application too

Comment: Not necessarily. Winforms is still great and a viable option for lightweight applications.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll -- And WPF has some ridiculously stupid shortcomings from which winforms doesn't suffer.  Source:  me, [this](http://loyc-etc.blogspot.com/2011/07/why-wpf-sucks.html), and many more.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll  I used that and it worked. And you were v quick. You can post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Create a label with location and size of textbox. Set border, background, etc to appear like a disabled textbox. Ensure that the textboxes z-order is on top (Bring to Front), and set it's visible property to false.

- On the label's click handler, set the textbox's Visibility to true.
- On the textbox's TextChange handler, set the labels Text property to equal the textbox's Text property.
- On the textbox's LostFocus handler, set the textbox's Visibility to false.

Comment: You could implement this as a reusable UserControl. This would be my preference rather than mucking around with the look and feel of the textbox which can be awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the text box's MouseDown event, and its parent's mousedown event. If the textbox is disabled, *the MouseDown event will be handled by the parent*. Ding!

I'm assuming the parent is a Form called Form1. It's possible that if the direct parent is a Panel or something, the Form will get the event anyhow. But you can figure that out easily.

```
private void textBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).Enabled = !(sender as TextBox).Enabled;
}

private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var rect = RectangleToClient(textBox1.RectangleToScreen(textBox1.ClientRectangle));

    if (rect.Contains(e.Location))
    {
        textBox1.Enabled = !textBox1.Enabled;

        //  I added this because it felt very wrong for the TextBox not 
        //  to gain focus when I enable-clicked it. I think you'll agree.
        if (textBox1.Enabled)
        {
            textBox1.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

The people advising you to try WPF are right; it's often painful, but at the end of the day it's amazingly good. I'd hate to go back to WiFo now. But if you need to get the feature done with your current code base, this kludge, hideous though it may be, will get you there.